# How to display the currecy symbol opportunity amount field based on the country name

Tags: opportunity, custom-field

I would like to show the currency symbol in the opportunity amount field  based on the country name(Country field is referred from he account field)

Comment: I see you've tagged this with custom-field. Are you wanting to display this in a custom field? Normally, assuming the org has multi-currency enabled, currency is set by the User's locale. If you're in a multi-currency org, there's also the issue of exchange rates, how they're calculated or when they're updated. What you're asking isn't trivial and the answer would depend on how your org manages currency exchanges assuming you want to display it in a custom field. Not possible in the standard field on a standard detail page.